# What to call a class/method for 'waiting till user has stopped clicking'

Tags: naming

I have a static class with a single method, which I use for delaying an action until the user has stopped clicking/typing/whatever:

```
public void SomeControl_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     // DoSomething once user has stopped clicking for 300ms
     MyClass.MyMethod(() => DoSomething(), 300);
}
```

Currently I've gone for `DelayAction.StartNew`, but that doesn't really convey what it does. I wondered about `Stabilize`, but I'm not sure that's any clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DelayAction.OnIdleUser
```

Since "being idle" means no activity, I'd go for this naming.

Comment: I think I'd prefer `OnUserIdle`, but still a good suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

`DelayAction.OnTimerExpired()`